# docker-compose up -d redpanda not working

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I just downloaded a github materialize demo app; when doing a `docker-compose version`:

```
docker-compose version
docker-compose version 1.29.2, build unknown
docker-py version: 5.0.3
CPython version: 3.6.9
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
```

But when I run `docker-compose up -d redpanda`:

`docker-compose up -d redpanda`

```
ERROR:
        Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any
        parent. Are you in the right directory?
        Supported filenames: docker-compose.yml, docker-compose.yaml, compose.yml, compose.yaml
```

Comment: Make sure you run it in the right directory that contains the `docker-compose.yaml`.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/